# Block malicious referral sites

Tags: javascript, security, .htaccess, web-traffic

My site is getting a lot of traffic from sites with malicious javascript (see below)

I don't completely understand the purpose, but I think the idea is to piggyback off my site's high traffic and manipulate their own traffic statistics.

I tried blocking the referral URLs (they are fake blogspot sites) with .htaccess, but that didn't work.  Is there any other way I can get rid of this garbage traffic?  My site run on a dedicated server, so if there is anything I can do beyond .htaccess (as suggested here http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml), please let me know.

This is the malicious code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sLocation = document.referrer.toLocaleLowerCase();
//Links to boost
var rDomains = ["http://site.com/"];
//Allowed domain referrer
var aDomains = [".com"];
var valid = 0;

//Valid referrer
for (i=0;i<aDomains.length;i++) {
//Check referrer
if (sLocation.indexOf(aDomains[i], 0) > -1) 
{
valid = 1;
break;
}
}

//Valid referrer
if (valid == 1) 
{
//Loop
for (i=0;i<rDomains.length;i++) {
//alert(rDomains[i]);
invisibleWindow("mydiv" + i,rDomains[i]);
}
}

function invisibleWindow(iframeID, url) {
divel = document.createElement("div");
divel.id = "div" + iframeID;
divel.style.width = "5px"; 
divel.style.height = "5px";
divel.style.visibility = "hidden";

//Add div
document.body.appendChild(divel);

domiframe = document.createElement("iframe");
domiframe.id = iframeID; 
domiframe.src = url;
domiframe.style.width = "5px"; 
domiframe.style.height = "5px";
domiframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

var divid = document.getElementById("div" + iframeID);
divid.appendChild(domiframe);
}

</script>
```

This is presumably written by the author of the code:

http://seotipsnewbie.blogspot.com/2011/12/script-to-get-unlimited-traffic-for.html

Comment: I'm sure the purpose is much more nefarious than manipulating their traffic. I'm sure there's a iframe somewhere and they're doing something like recording keystrokes on your site to steal passwords, sending it back to their server via ajax, or some other xss or xsrf attack. Nobody would target anyone simply to inflate hit counts.  Other than inflating ad revenue, there's no ROI and no logical motovation. I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: If you know the ip addresses and have access to the firewall, the best way is to block them at the firewall level.

Comment: Depending on your budget, a good Web Application Firewall (different than a standard firewall)is a good idea. Also try at security.stackexchqnge.com.

Comment: I don't know the IP addresses, but I know the URLs of sites containing the malicious code.  I'm not sure if the IP addresses are relevant.  I'm not trying to block the visitors, because the visitors are just victims of the referring sites.

Comment: I agree with @DavidStratton. It's unlikely they are doing this to try to raise their hit counts. You should add the header "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" in the responses for the pages that you are receiving the most traffic from those referral sites on. This blocks embedding inside an iframe and might actually help reduce this traffic. Help protect your users :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the referrer url where these attempted attacks are originating from (which you appear to) you could potentially block access by simply directing traffic from that referrer url away.

Doing this with JavaScript is however not particularly reliable as they could simply turn JavaScript off. Or not attack your site while coming from their own (no referrer url).

```
var block = ['url1', 'url2'];
for (var b = block.length; b--;) {
    if (document.referrer.match(block[b]))
        window.location = "http://google.com/";
}
```

Doing this in a server side language would be somewhat more reliable, especially as you could collect the offending ip addresses and block based off of that instead of refferer urls, which I must say I don't have much faith in as a solution.
Even better would be to do it using a firewall as previously mentioned and blocking access to the server entirely.

In PHP you would use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] for the referrer url, and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for the IP address if my memory serves me. The code itself would be quite similar:

```
$block = ['url1', 'url2'];
foreach ($block as $value) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] == $value)
        header('Location: http://google.com/');
}
```

You could probably use == ( wouldn't trust === off the top of my head as it's a value coming from a dom node ) instead of match in the javascript one as well.. It's been a long day and match came to mind first for whatever reason.